# In R connected to an Access Database through ODBC, how can I update a text field?

Tags: r, sql-update, odbc, r-dbi

I have R linked to an Access database using the ODBC and DBI packages. I scoured the internet and couldn't find a way to write an update query, so I'm using the dbSendStatement function to update entries individually. Combined with a for loop, this effectively works like an update query with one snag - when I try to update any field in the database that is text I get an error that says **"[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] One of your parameters is invalid."**

```
DBI::dbSendStatement(conn = dB.Connection, statement = paste("UPDATE DC_FIMs_BLDG_Lvl SET kWh_Rate_Type = ",dquote(BLDG.LVL.Details[i,5])," WHERE FIM_ID = ",BLDG.LVL.Details[i,1]," AND BUILDING_ID = ",BLDG.LVL.Details[i,2],";", sep = ""))
```

If it's easier, when pasted, the code reads like this:

```
DBI::dbSendStatement(conn = dB.Connection, statement = paste("UPDATE DC_FIMs_BLDG_Lvl SET kWh_Rate_Type = “Incremental” WHERE FIM_ID = 26242807 AND BUILDING_ID = 515;", sep = ""))
```

Comment: A quick look would suggest that `dquote` is quoting your column in the wrong way. You should instead use the buildin quotation functions from `DBI` `dbQuoteIdentifier` (columns, table names), `dbQuoteLiteral` (values that are not strings) and `dbQuoteString` (for strings). I'd suggest writing out your query manually, testing it and then automate it. However, be wary! If your program has user input, it is exceedlingly easy to inject Access SQL code. Always end your statement using ";" (as Access doesnt accept multiple statements) and always quote your values.

Comment: This was answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971555/in-r-connected-to-a-database-through-odbc-how-do-i-disconnect-after-running-one

Comment: You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. While there are security concerns about malicious [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's a single data analyst running the query. Both `DBI` (with `odbc`) and `RODBC` support [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries), either natively or via add-ons.

Comment: Also, I'd use `dbExecute` instead of `dbSendStatement`. (I see no indication that you are clearing the result from your code, which is a little sloppy. `dbExecute` does this for you.)